# Failed to compile fragment shader. at createFragmentShader

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm unsure how to investigate this, but I'm getting this error when I try to do face detection in tensor js.

```
Failed to compile fragment shader.
Error: Failed to compile fragment shader.
 at createFragmentShader (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:47522:11)
 at Module.compileProgram (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:25672:91)
 at http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:20574:56
 at MathBackendWebGL.getAndSaveBinary (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:20616:31)
 at MathBackendWebGL.runWebGLProgram (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:20573:25)
 at Object.fromPixels \[as kernelFunc\] (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:32109:23)
 at kernelFunc (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:61598:22)
 at http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:61664:19
 at Engine.scopedRun (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:61452:19)
 at Engine.runKernelFunc (http://localhost:3000/-Emotional-Analysis-Using-CNN/static/js/bundle.js:61660:10)
```

It is coming from this chunk of code:

```
let gray = new cv.Mat();
let faces = new cv.RectVector();
...
try
{
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, faces, 1.1, 3, 0, minSize, maxSize);
}
catch(ptr)
{
    let err = cv.exceptionFromPtr(ptr)
    console.log("An error occurred: " + err.msg);
}
// Extract features and classify emotions using the pre-trained model
for (let i = 0; i < faces.size(); ++i) {
    let face = faces.get(i);
    let faceImg = gray.roi(face);
    cv.resize(faceImg, faceImg, new cv.Size(48, 48));
    tf.tidy(() => {
        let tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(faceImg).mean(2).toFloat().div(255.0).expandDims(0); //Error here in fromPixels
        let prediction = model.predict(tensor);
        let emotions = ['Angry', 'Disgust', 'Fear', 'Happy', 'Sad', 'Surprise', 'Neutral'];
        ...
    });
    faceImg.delete();
}
```

Any idea on what could be happening? Seems like a weird webgl issue and this happens in both Chrome and Firefox.